# Component Vue2-google-map error while using different layout in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue2-google-maps

I'm building a simple CRUD app with Nuxt.js. For the index page. Need to show the google map by using vue2-google-map.

It's working by refreshing or routing on same layout.
But it doesn't work,(google map error occuring)
If I visit index page which includes map component from the page that has a differnt layout.

Folder structure.

Layout/ default, register
Page/ index,user, signin, signup

index, user - default layout
signin, signup - register layout

It's working just access url by refreshing on index url.
But It's not working from signin page because signin page has different layout from index page.
**I tried to change layout of signin page to default, then it works**

index.vue

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex>
      <GmapMap :center="center" :zoom="7" style="width:100%; height: 80vh;">
      </GmapMap>
....
```

signin.vue

```
....
export default {
  **layout: 'register',**
  data: () => ({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    role: '',
....
```

[image: success loading by refreshing or from same layout]
[image: signinpage with the differnt layout]
[image: error showing after visiting from signin page which has differnt layout]